# Product image not displaying in Product listing Page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, product-images

I have created one attribute called `imageUrl` for importing product image url. And made some changes in `media.phtml` and `list.phtml`. Now product images not displaying in product list page  but it displays images in product details page..

```
<img src="<?php echo $_product->getData('imageurl') ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin, Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`.

Select/Edit `imageUrl` attribute > Select `Properties` tab.

In `Frontend Properties` block, set `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes`.
Press Save.

Now check `list` page, it should show images now.

Comment: It would also be worth making sure you clear the magento cache and reindex the product attributes (If not set to rerindex on save)

Comment: its not working... :(

Comment: what's your `attribute_code` ? `imageUrl`  OR `imageurl` ? Have you cleared Cache and did re-index ?

Comment: `imageurl` .. .

Comment: please share a full code you did in `list.phtml`

Comment: now its displaying in product list page.. But not in cart page

Comment: in cart page, you have to load `catalog/product` model. and then use `getData('imageurl')`

Comment: ok.. can I set url in a variable and import only image name .. for example now image urls like `http://int1.co/admin/backEnd/uploads/4717602016_05_12_03_28_35pm.png` i would like to add only image name in csv file `4717602016_05_12_03_28_35pm.png` coz `http://int1.co/admin/backEnd/uploads/` is common.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple stores, make sure the default images for selected for each store:

[image]

The attribute `media_gallery` is used to store the collection of images for each product. Be sure that the *Small Image* is selected for the store view product listing. (*Base Image* is used on the product page, *Thumbnail* is for the cart page.)

If the images are added programmatically or during import or by APIs, be sure the specify the store. To use the same images across stores, set `store_id = 0`.

If the default images should be the same across the stores, then you can set the 3 image attributes to *Global* in the backend *Manage Attributes*. The image attribute codes are `image`, `small_image`, and `thumbnail`. But beware, when the attributes are saved, all the values for `store_id > 0` will be removed in the backend type tables, which is `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for the images. However, you would still need to set the defaults like the screenshot above.